# How to Inject Kubernetes Service to my java class?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, kubernetes, microservices, fabric8

I have created and deployed successfully one service in `kubernetes` named *rest_api_service*.

I have another project which needs to call a resource from *rest_api_service*. So, in order to get out the IP of my service, I tried to inject:

```
@Inject
@ServiceName("luz-person-service")
String serivceUrl;
```

But my Eclipse shows me this warn message:

```
> No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-346
> §5.2.2]
```

Therefore I can not build it in `wildfly`.

Currently, I am working only on pure `Java EE 7` and I'm using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>fabric8-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Pods are automatically injected with environment variables containing information about services in their namespace.  As an example, say your pod is in a namespace that also contains a service named 'foo'.  The containers in your pod will be injected with:

```
FOO_SERVICE_HOST=<host service foo is reachable at>
FOO_SERVICE_PORT=<port service foo is reachable at>
```

as well as docker-links style environment variables.  Check out [the docs here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#discovering-services).